# Getting NullPointerException in initialize method of Controller JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, initialization, stage

Following is the NullPointerException I'm getting in initialize method of controller class:

```
`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/C:/Users/W7/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PivotNSE/dist/run2050028213/PivotNSE.jar!/pivotnse/popupFXML.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at pivotnse.PivotFXController.handleLoadButton(PivotFXController.java:173)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pivotnse.PivotFXController.initialize(PivotFXController.java:294)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 66 more`
```

What I am trying to do is, when myLoadButton is clicked, a new window pops up
and shows in the Label of new window all the Symbols that are currently getting
"downloaded"! (kind of like "real time update" to user). Just so the user knows, what's happening.
Following is the Code:

```
 public class PivotFXController implements Initializable {

        final ObservableList<GetPivots> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        @FXML
        private TableView<GetPivots> pivotTable;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<GetPivots, String> symbolColumn;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<GetPivots, String> pivotColumn;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<GetPivots, String> r1Column;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<GetPivots, String> r2Column;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<GetPivots, String> r3Column;

        @FXML
        private TableColumn<GetPivots, String> s1Column;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<GetPivots, String> s2Column;
        @FXML
        private TableColumn<GetPivots, String> s3Column;
        @FXML
        private Label statusLabel;
        @FXML
        private Button myLoadButton;
        @FXML
        private Button doneButton;

        @FXML
        private TextField symbolField;

        private String SYMBOLS_FILE = "SYMBOLS.txt";

        private static List<String> symbolList = new ArrayList<String>();


        private boolean handleSymbol(String symbol) {
            System.out.println(symbol + " is the input");
            // statusLabel.setText("Downloading... " + symbol);
            FetchDataNSE fdn = new FetchDataNSE();

            if (fdn.getDataNSE(symbol).size() > 0) {
                CalculatePivot cp = new CalculatePivot(fdn.getDataNSE(symbol));
                GetPivots gp = new GetPivots(cp);
                data.add(gp);
                //   statusLabel.setText(symbol + " " + "Downloaded!");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }



        @FXML
        private void handleLoadButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
            Stage stage;
            Parent root;
            if (event.getSource() == myLoadButton) {
                //get reference to the button's stage         
                stage = (Stage) myLoadButton.getScene().getWindow();
                //load up OTHER FXML document
                root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("popupFXML.fxml"));// <-- ****this line is causing problem**** I am getting NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION from 1st line in `initialize` method WHY?
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                stage.setTitle("DOWNLOADING STATUS");
                stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                stage.showAndWait();
                loadSymbols();

            } else {
                stage = (Stage) doneButton.getScene().getWindow();
                root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("pivotFXGUI.fxml"));
                Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
            }


        }

        private void loadSymbols() {
            data.clear();
            symbolList.clear();

            BufferedReader br = null;

            try {

                String sCurrentLine;

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(SYMBOLS_FILE));

                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    symbolList.add(sCurrentLine.trim());
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null) {
                        br.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            for (String sym : symbolList) {
                statusLabel.setText("Downloading... " + sym);
                handleSymbol(sym);
            }

            statusLabel.setText("LOADING SYMBOLS DONE!");
        }




        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // 1st line below gives NullPointerException! why does that happen?
            symbolColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("symbolProperty"));
            pivotColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pivotProperty"));
            r1Column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("r1Property"));
            r2Column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("r2Property"));
            r3Column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("r3Property"));
            s1Column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("s1Property"));
            s2Column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("s2Property"));
            s3Column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("s3Property"));
            pivotTable.setItems(data);

            // myLoadButton.fire();
            //  pivotTable.getColumns().addAll(symbolColumn,s3Column, s2Column,s1Column, pivotColumn, r1Column, r2Column, r3Column  );

        }


    }
`
```

Why is the 1st line in the "initialize" method throwing NullPointerException!?
What am I doing *incorrectly* in `handleLoadButton(..)` method and `initialize(..)` method?
When I remove everything from `initialize` method program opens up new window when I click myLoadButton, but then NullPointerException occurs when `loadSymbols()` method is called...

ALSO:::
`at pivotnse.PivotFXController.handleLoadButton(PivotFXController.java:173)
        ... 58 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at pivotnse.PivotFXController.initialize(PivotFXController.java:294)`
line 173 is following:::
`root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("popupFXML.fxml"));`
and line 294 is the 1st line in `initialize()` method.

Comment: Please boil down your code to the minimum which shows the problem. Nobobody want to read such big copy/paste desert.

Comment: can you host somewhere the files to have a look ?

Comment: I'm wondering why loading `popupFXML.fxml` would fire `PivotFXController.initialize()` in the first place?  You'd expect it to call `PopupFXML.initialize()`, no?  Got a `fx:controller="<controller>"` attribute in `popupFXML.fxml` and what does it say?

Comment: fx:controller="pivotnse.PivotFXController" <-- this is in popupFXML.fxml, PivotFXController is the main controller which popupFXML.fxml also uses

Answer (score 1):

Probably "symbolColumn" has not been initialized. Maybe you have forgotten or misspelled the fx:id in your fxml-file.

Comment: Problem occurs only when `myLoadButton` is clicked! Everything else works fine!

Answer (score 1):

The relation between fxml documents and the controllers is 1:1 by design.  In other words, each fxml document should have its own controller.

Right now you're trying to load `popupFXML.fxml` with `pivotnse.PivotFXController` as controller.  So your `initialize()` executes `symbolColumn.setCellValueFactory()` while `symbolColumn` wasn't injected, because `popupFXML.fxml` doesn't have a `symbolColumn`.  Result: NPE.

You should make a seperate controller class for `popupFXML.fxml` and reference it in your fxml like `fx:controller="pivotnse.PopupFXMLController"`

Comment: [2 FXML 1 Controller](http://www.javafxtutorials.com/tutorials/switching-to-different-screens-in-javafx-and-fxml/) @Arjan Here author uses same controller for 2 fxml files, see the first 5th point from bottom of the page...

Comment: @Bigshot Yeah, that author coincidentally has 2 fxml files which are quite simple, so in his case it can work.  You have a `TableView` in one fxml file, you're setting the cellValueFactory of its columns in the controller's initialize method.  But you don't have the TableView in the other fxml file, so setting the cellValueFactory results in a NPE.  Btw, *The 1:1 association between an FXML document and its controller is by design*, those are the words of JavaFX' designer Greg Brown...  Feel free to ignore them and follow some other pattern, of course :)

Comment: That tutorial is absolute nonsense and is full of errors. Don't believe everything you read on the Internet. Each FXML file should have its own controller class.